# Sockets in Ubuntu Touch Apps

Tags: networking, application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, javascript

I am creating an IRC client for the Ubuntu App Showdown. I need a way to be able to access an IRC server in QML (or JavaScript). What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this more like a question for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is no QML module that can help you accessing IRC servers, you will probably need to write a QML plugin in C++ that does that work as a backend. You can then use QML to implement the UI frontend.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to port irc-chatter (https://github.com/Venemo/irc-chatter) to Ubuntu-touch. Source is written in Qt/Qml (c++, see communiircclient.cpp).

Comment: I tested using a C++-function in qml on ubuntu-touch: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/266628/qt5-qtcreator-using-a-cfunction-in-main-qml-to-create-a-file-tmp

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not as performant as the QML solution, you can you IRC-js to communicate with the IRC Server. Here is the GibHub link to the project https://github.com/gf3/IRC-js